# How are transactions classified that cause a smart contract to send ether to an EOA?

Tags: transactions, ether, message

Let's say I send a transaction to smart contract which functions cause Ether to be send to another EOA. The Ether that the EOA receives must obliviously stem from a transaction. How would that transaction look like in Etherscan? Who would be the sender?
I feel like I am basing my question on a false assumption...

Thanks!

Comment: What is your question exactly? How to see in Etherscan that a transaction has the behaviour you describe? If that's the case, you should just go to the transaction page in Etherscan and check the "Tokens transferred" section.

Comment: @FrancoVictorio If an EOA receives Ether from a smart contract, how is this described in Etherscan?
Will it just be a transaction between the sending EOA (initiator or txn) and the receiving EOA?

Comment: I think you can go to the receiver EOA page and then look in the Internal transactions tab.

Comment: @FrancoVictorio Got it, thanks!